# Lookup URLs from list of IP addresses

Tags: router, ip

My router log notes activity by IP address but I want to see the corresponding URL addresses instead.  Is there a way to derive the URLs from the IPs--in bulk/batch--without having to do it manually/individually one line at-a-time?

Comment: @Franciso - You do understand that multiple website can have the same ip address.  What you want is not realistic.

Comment: You may have a problem with shared hosted sites, if someone visited [198.252.206.16](http://198.252.206.16) did they go to  `stackoverflow.com`, `workplace.stackexchange.com`, `cs.stackexchange.com`, `dsp.stackexchange.com`, `crypto.stackexchange.com`, `movies.stackexchange.com`, `raspberrypi.stackexchange.com`, `academia.stackexchange.com`, `mechanics.stackexchange.com`, `history.stackexchange.com`, `biology.stackexchange.com`, `outdoors.stackexchange.com`, `bitcoin.stackexchange.com`, `quant.stackexchange.com`, `bricks.stackexchange.com`, or `pm.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: @Scott but still, IP addresses do direct to the "main page". Sure it won't give a precise name, but for some purposes it might be sufficient.
What is your router manufacturer and OS? It might help those who are answering.

Comment: On what OS are you using？

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list, you could do this pretty easily on any OS using [Python](http://python.org)'s built in `socket` module.

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyaddr('198.252.206.16')
```

That returns:

```
('stackoverflow.com', ['16.206.252.198.in-addr.arpa'], ['198.252.206.16'])
```

So scriptifything that wouldn't be difficult at all, just have an ip per line in a file and do something like:

```
import socket

fi = open('iplist.txt')
for line in fi.readlines():
    print( socket.gethostbyaddr( line )[0] )
fi.close()
```

Of course, you could adjust the output to write the IP and domain name to another file if you so desire.

However, as @ScottChamberlain points out - this may not always resolve for site that share an IP (subdomains and such included).

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a text file `ips.txt` with a list of ip addresses:

```
$ cat ips.txt | xargs host
```

Or you can write an elegant bash script to format results:

```
for ip in $(cat ips.txt); do
    domain_names=$(host $ip | grep "domain name" | awk '{print $5}' | tr ".\\n" " ")

    # test first char of domain names
    if [ -n ${domain_names:0:1} ]; then
        echo "$ip $domain_names" 
    else
        echo "$ip not found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP is using Linux paired with BASH?  I think that is a fundamental flaw in your answer, even if it may work (didn't test it, but I assume you did before posting).