# How to input a list of websites, and it output list of IP's?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ip, domain

Does anyone know of a way to simply output a website's IP address, that could be input in an excel sheet?
Ex. 
www.cnn.com
www.google.com
www.superuser.com

IP1
IP2
IP3

Something in cmd would be fantastic.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: @terdon Win 7 Pro

Comment: Most commands I know would only return the DNS information which isn't actually the address of the website but say a load balancer or `cn server`

Comment: @Ramhound Would you know of a web resource similar to who.is where I could put in multiple landing pages and it output the IP?

Comment: If you're not afraid of scripting it, I have [an answer](http://superuser.com/questions/635503/lookup-urls-from-list-of-ip-addresses/635513#635513) that is somewhat related and could easily be tweaked for you (note: instead of gethostbyaddr you'd tweak that)

Comment: @user35983 - Why don't you just write a .bat that runs and outputs a ping command.  Would take 5 minutes at most to write u don't do product recommendations

Comment: Just a reminder, a list of IP addresses may or may not be useful. DNS names/Websites are not 1 <=> 1 to IP addresses. A website may have more than one IP address (server farm). An IP address may have more than one Website (shared hosting).

Answer (score 4):

NirSoft's [FastResolver](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/fastresolver.html) tool seems to do exactly what you want.

Type in a list of hostnames you want to get IPs for:

[image]

It will return the resolved IPs for the hostnames:

[image]

You can then copy & paste the returned data directly into Excel, or you can get an HTML report (in a table) for it.

[image]

You can also save the results in a variety of formats using the Save Items option:

[image]

You could save as CSV and open that with Excel, saving it in the format you desire.

It also works the other way (convert IP to hostname). You can also search a range of IPs and it will resolve the hostnames for those as well (useful for a local network!).

Answer (score 3):

```
echo off  
cls  
set /p input= Website:  
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ping /n 1 /w 1 %input% ^| find "Pinging"') do set ipaddress=%%B  
cls  
echo %ipaddress%  
pause > nul
```

to loop the script, just do this:

```
echo off  

:loop  
cls  
set /p input= Website:  
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ping /n 1 /w 1 %input% ^| find "Pinging"') do set ipaddress=%%B  
cls  
echo %ipaddress%  
pause 

goto loop
```

Also, 'grep' should work for pulling a list of domains from a .txt. Just capture each line as a workable variable:

```
set site1=www.google.com  
set site2=www.whatever.com

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ping /n 1 /w 1 %site1% ^| find "Pinging"') do set ipaddress=%%B
```

You'll have to play around with your script a little bit..

Comment: Any idea on how to modify this to accept a list of domains? Possibly from a text file? If not, any way to look this do it asks again and again for website? This is very useful!

Comment: "Grep" should work